# Alter $resource default methods

Tags: angularjs

How can I alter and add to the default $resource return object methods?

The return object defaults in question are (from the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)):

*A resource "class" object with methods for the default set of resource actions optionally extended with custom actions. The default set contains these actions:*

```
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

As I understand, this does not follow the [restful principles](http://codeplanet.io/principles-good-restful-api-design/) so good in regard to when to use POST and PUT. Perhaps it would be better to have the following methods:

```
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'PUT'},
  'create': {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

Is there a way to change the default object that $resource creates, so I do not need to alter each resource I am creating with $resource?

Comment: I haven't found a way to do that. But if it helps, when you redefine the methods you only need to define the ones you want to change or add. I typically add one method `update` which does a PUT (equivalent to your save). And that's it. I don't need to modify the others. If you are using Rails, I've recently switched to using [Angular Rails Resource](https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource) and love it. It just does what you want, and handles nested resources beautifully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [talk at ng-conf 2014](https://youtu.be/62RvRQuMVyg?t=24m24s) by Googles DoubleClick team that was a real good answer to this question and beyond. Basically they create a apiProvider that uses and extends $resource.

They also have a [github gist](https://gist.github.com/jelbourn/6276338) that would be too long to include here.